# TCL script to remove duplicate elements from the list but not the first element of each element

Tags: tcl

I am having one input file as stated below

```
echo $test_list 
assign mbist_in.BIST_SETUP = BIST_SETUP;
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en = ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en;
assign mbist_in.bistEn = bistEn;                                    
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_en = ltest_to_en;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE;
assign mbist_in.BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE;  
assign mbist_in.BIST_SELECT = BIST_SELECT;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITEENABLE = BIST_WRITEENABLE;                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN = BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN;          
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_EN0 = BIST_COLLAR_EN0;                      
assign mbist_in.BIST_ASYNC_RESET = BIST_ASYNC_RESET;                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR = BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR;
assign mbist_in.BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR = BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR = BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_SETUP = BIST_COLLAR_SETUP;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT = BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT;                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR = BIST_CLEAR;                                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_HOLD = BIST_COLLAR_HOLD;                            
assign mbist_in.MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2 = MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2;            
assign mbist_in.BIST_BANK_ADD = BIST_BANK_ADD;                                  
assign mbist_in.BIST_COL_ADD = BIST_COL_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_ROW_ADD = BIST_ROW_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITE_DATA = BIST_WRITE_DATA;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_SETUP = BIST_SETUP;                                        
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en = ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en;            
assign mbist_in.bistEn = bistEn;                                                
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_en = ltest_to_en;                                      
assign mbist_in.BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE;        
assign mbist_in.BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE;          
assign mbist_in.BIST_SELECT = BIST_SELECT;                                      
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITEENABLE = BIST_WRITEENABLE;                            
assign mbist_in.BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN = BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN;                  
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_EN0 = BIST_COLLAR_EN0;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_ASYNC_RESET = BIST_ASYNC_RESET;                            
assign mbist_in.BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR = BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR;
assign mbist_in.BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR = BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR = BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_SETUP = BIST_COLLAR_SETUP;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT = BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT;                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR = BIST_CLEAR;                                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_HOLD = BIST_COLLAR_HOLD;                            
assign mbist_in.MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2 = MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2;            
assign mbist_in.BIST_BANK_ADD = BIST_BANK_ADD;                                  
assign mbist_in.BIST_COL_ADD = BIST_COL_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_ROW_ADD = BIST_ROW_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITE_DATA = BIST_WRITE_DATA;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_SETUP = BIST_SETUP;                                        
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en = ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en;            
assign mbist_in.bistEn = bistEn;                                                
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_en = ltest_to_en;                                      
assign mbist_in.BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE;        
assign mbist_in.BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE;          
assign mbist_in.BIST_SELECT = BIST_SELECT;                                      
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITEENABLE = BIST_WRITEENABLE;                            
assign mbist_in.BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN = BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN;                  
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_EN0 = BIST_COLLAR_EN0;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_ASYNC_RESET = BIST_ASYNC_RESET;                            
assign mbist_in.BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR = BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR;
assign mbist_in.BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR = BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR = BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_SETUP = BIST_COLLAR_SETUP;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT = BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT;                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR = BIST_CLEAR;                                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_HOLD = BIST_COLLAR_HOLD;                            
assign mbist_in.MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2 = MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2;            
assign mbist_in.BIST_BANK_ADD = BIST_BANK_ADD;                                  
assign mbist_in.BIST_COL_ADD = BIST_COL_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_ROW_ADD = BIST_ROW_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITE_DATA = BIST_WRITE_DATA;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_SETUP = BIST_SETUP;                                        
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en = ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en;            
assign mbist_in.bistEn = bistEn;                                                
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_en = ltest_to_en;                                      
assign mbist_in.BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE;        
assign mbist_in.BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE;          
assign mbist_in.BIST_SELECT = BIST_SELECT;                                      
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITEENABLE = BIST_WRITEENABLE;                            
assign mbist_in.BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN = BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN;                  
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_EN0 = BIST_COLLAR_EN0;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_ASYNC_RESET = BIST_ASYNC_RESET;                            
assign mbist_in.BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR = BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR;
assign mbist_in.BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR = BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR = BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_SETUP = BIST_COLLAR_SETUP;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT = BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT;                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR = BIST_CLEAR;                                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_HOLD = BIST_COLLAR_HOLD;                            
assign mbist_in.MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2 = MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2;            
assign mbist_in.BIST_BANK_ADD = BIST_BANK_ADD;                                  
assign mbist_in.BIST_COL_ADD = BIST_COL_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_ROW_ADD = BIST_ROW_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITE_DATA = BIST_WRITE_DATA;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_SETUP = BIST_SETUP;                                        
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en = ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en;            
assign mbist_in.bistEn = bistEn;                                                
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_en = ltest_to_en;                                      
assign mbist_in.BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE;        
assign mbist_in.BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE;          
assign mbist_in.BIST_SELECT = BIST_SELECT;                                      
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITEENABLE = BIST_WRITEENABLE;                            
assign mbist_in.BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN = BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN;                  
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_EN0 = BIST_COLLAR_EN0;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_ASYNC_RESET = BIST_ASYNC_RESET;                            
assign mbist_in.BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR = BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR;
assign mbist_in.BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR = BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR = BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_SETUP = BIST_COLLAR_SETUP;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT = BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT;                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR = BIST_CLEAR;                                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_HOLD = BIST_COLLAR_HOLD;                            
assign mbist_in.MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2 = MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2;            
assign mbist_in.BIST_BANK_ADD = BIST_BANK_ADD;                                  
assign mbist_in.BIST_COL_ADD = BIST_COL_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_ROW_ADD = BIST_ROW_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITE_DATA = BIST_WRITE_DATA;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_SETUP = BIST_SETUP;                                        
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en = ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en;            
assign mbist_in.bistEn = bistEn;                                                
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_en = ltest_to_en;                                      
assign mbist_in.BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE;        
assign mbist_in.BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE;          
assign mbist_in.BIST_SELECT = BIST_SELECT;                                      
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITEENABLE = BIST_WRITEENABLE;                            
assign mbist_in.BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN = BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN;                  
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_EN0 = BIST_COLLAR_EN0;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_ASYNC_RESET = BIST_ASYNC_RESET;                            
assign mbist_in.BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR = BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR;
assign mbist_in.BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR = BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR = BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_SETUP = BIST_COLLAR_SETUP;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT = BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT;                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR = BIST_CLEAR;                                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_HOLD = BIST_COLLAR_HOLD;                            
assign mbist_in.MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2 = MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2;            
assign mbist_in.BIST_BANK_ADD = BIST_BANK_ADD;                                  
assign mbist_in.BIST_COL_ADD = BIST_COL_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_ROW_ADD = BIST_ROW_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITE_DATA = BIST_WRITE_DATA;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_SETUP = BIST_SETUP;                                        
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en = ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en;            
assign mbist_in.bistEn = bistEn;                                                
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_en = ltest_to_en;                                      
assign mbist_in.BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE;        
assign mbist_in.BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE;          
assign mbist_in.BIST_SELECT = BIST_SELECT;                                      
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITEENABLE = BIST_WRITEENABLE;                            
assign mbist_in.BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN = BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN;                  
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_EN0 = BIST_COLLAR_EN0;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_ASYNC_RESET = BIST_ASYNC_RESET;                            
assign mbist_in.BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR = BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR;
assign mbist_in.BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR = BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR = BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_SETUP = BIST_COLLAR_SETUP;                          
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT = BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT;                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR = BIST_CLEAR;                                        
assign mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_HOLD = BIST_COLLAR_HOLD;                            
assign mbist_in.MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2 = MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2;            
assign mbist_in.BIST_BANK_ADD = BIST_BANK_ADD;                                  
assign mbist_in.BIST_COL_ADD = BIST_COL_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_ROW_ADD = BIST_ROW_ADD;                                    
assign mbist_in.BIST_WRITE_DATA = BIST_WRITE_DATA;                              
assign mbist_in.BIST_SETUP = BIST_SETUP;                                        
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en = ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en;
assign mbist_in.bistEn = bistEn;
assign mbist_in.ltest_to_en = ltest_to_en;
assign mbist_in.BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE;
assign mbist_in.BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE = BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE;
```

Now this carries lots of duplicate lines , I need to remove the duplicate lines

I have created below script as stated below

```
set new4 {}
foreach item $test_list {
if {[lsearch $new $item ] < 0} {
 lappend new4 $item 
 }
}

echo $new4 
assign mbist_in.BIST_SETUP = {BIST_SETUP;} mbist_in.ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en {ltest_to_mcp_bounding_en;} mbist_in.bistEn {bistEn;} mbist_in.ltest_to_en {ltest_to_en;} mbist_in.BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE {BIST_EVEN_GROUPWRITEENABLE;} mbist_in.BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE {BIST_ODD_GROUPWRITEENABLE;} mbist_in.BIST_SELECT {BIST_SELECT;} mbist_in.BIST_WRITEENABLE {BIST_WRITEENABLE;} mbist_in.BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN {BIST_DATA_POLARITY_EN;} mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_EN0 {BIST_COLLAR_EN0;} mbist_in.BIST_ASYNC_RESET {BIST_ASYNC_RESET;} mbist_in.BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR {BIST_TESTDATA_SELECT_TO_COLLAR;} mbist_in.BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR {BIST_ON_TO_COLLAR;} mbist_in.BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR {BIST_SHIFT_COLLAR;} mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_SETUP {BIST_COLLAR_SETUP;} mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT {BIST_CLEAR_DEFAULT;} mbist_in.BIST_CLEAR {BIST_CLEAR;} mbist_in.BIST_COLLAR_HOLD {BIST_COLLAR_HOLD;} mbist_in.MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2 {MBISTPG_RESET_REG_SETUP2;} mbist_in.BIST_BANK_ADD {BIST_BANK_ADD;} mbist_in.BIST_COL_ADD {BIST_COL_ADD;} mbist_in.BIST_ROW_ADD {BIST_ROW_ADD;} mbist_in.BIST_WRITE_DATA {BIST_WRITE_DATA;}
```

I am not getting assign statement in each and every line 
My output file should be having the entire list with assign statement in each and every line without duplicate lines  and new lines for each element starting with assign

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Your list is malformed. It looks like it doesn't have items for each line, but items for each word (by word, I mean character(s) separated by space here)

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work (except for a typo in the variable name), if you would feed it a list of lines, instead of a multi-line string.

To turn your data into a list of lines, use the `split` command:

```
set new4 {}
foreach item [split $test_list \n] {
    if {$item ni $new4} {
        lappend new4 $item 
    }
}

puts [join $new4 \n]
```

Note: `echo` is not a Tcl command. That's why I changed it to `puts`. I also switched to using the `ni` operator to look for an element in a list, although `lsearch` would work. But then it probably needs the -exact option as -glob is the default matching mechanism used by `lsearch`. And that's not what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

When doing this sort of thing, you need to both be careful as to what the list is a list of, and also mind the cost of checking what you have already printed (linear searches of growing lists are quadratically expensive in an algorithmic sense, which gets painful quickly).

Here's a way to fix both issues. The first is handled by splitting the input data by newline characters, and the second by using an associative map (an array or dictionary) to check if the item has never been seen before (the trick with `incr` is a simple way to do that in current Tcl versions).

```
foreach item [split $item \n] {
    if {[incr found($item)] == 1} {
        puts $item
    }
}
```